# Is there a way to check if 3x assets are the correct resolution without using simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to check if the 3x assets I have are in the correct resolution. I don't have my knowledge with Objective-C or Swift, so is there a way to check without using Xcode?

I have very basic knowledge of Swift and Xcode (navigating and such) so if someone can give me the steps I think I can do it.

I want to check this because I have a low resolution file with maximum output of 2x, so I'm trying find a way to get the 3x without losing quality by migrating the PSD file to AI.